# svn migration from one server to another in parts

Tags: svn

I have certain SVN repositories which I want to migrate to another server.

The first option available to me is that I should take the dump from source and load to destination. This load process is high time consumable and many times due to  network timed out, it stuck and I need to restart the entire process.

The other way, I am guessing, that the dump will be taken in parts, let say if I have REPO with 1000 revisions, then I would create 10 dumps each with 100 revision and load one by one in sequence.

My question is whether it is possible ? or there is some other way around.

Comment: Have you considered option c) "rsync the raw database"?

Comment: I have only URL for destination, it is a svn hosting

Comment: Does the hosting provider support svnsync uploads?

Comment: yes they do , but i believe that too is a slow thing

Comment: It is however resumable. You can restart a svnsync at any point.